# Currency Conversion wrong

Tags: apex, trigger, multi-currency, advanced

I'm trying to populate the sum(total selling price)of child object on to the "total order item value"{currecny data type field} of parent object. Here is the code

```
trigger Rollup on OSF_Order_Items__c (after delete,after insert,after update,after Undelete) {

set<Id>OpportunityIds=new set<Id>();
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isUnDelete){
for(OSF_Order_Items__c o:trigger.new){
OpportunityIds.add(o.Opportunity__c);
}
}
if(trigger.isDelete)
{
for(OSF_Order_Items__c o:trigger.old){
OpportunityIds.add(o.Opportunity__c);
}}
Map<Id,Double>OpportunityMap=new Map<Id,Double>();
for(AggregateResult q:[select Opportunity__c,sum(Total_Selling_Price__c)from OSF_Order_Items__c where Opportunity__c IN:OpportunityIds group by Opportunity__C]){
OpportunityMap.put((Id)q.get('Opportunity__c'),(Double)q.get('expr0'));
}
List<Opportunity>OpportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity o:[Select Id,**convertcurrency(Test_Total_Order_Item__c)** from Opportunity where Id IN:OpportunityIds]){
Double Item =OpportunityMap.get(o.Id);
o.Test_Total_Order_Item__c=Item;
OpportunitiesToUpdate.add(o);
}
update OpportunitiesToUpdate;
}
```

Problem: The vaule which was returned was not coorect. for example the value expected is USD 15,561 AND result is USD 11335. I observe 11335 is and euro euivalent of 1556l. my org currency is euro.

i want to display the sum of child along with userdefined currency on to the parent as it is. any luck?

Comment: Seriously check the link from my answer (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm), especially around GROUP BY. It's not "wrong", it's a well-documented behaviour with lots of examples what you can do about it.

Comment: i looked into that before writing the code.And i'm afraid how to loop throught each child record for converting and how to capture sum at the end

Comment: Most of the time you don't want to loop through them, wastes script statements and accumulates rounding errors. But you have GROUP BY already so just multiply it by EUR to USD conversion rate (the last select in my answer)

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24849/currency-fields-show-other-values-on-a-page-that-in-the-database

Comment: we enabled multi currency and advance currency management.so i thing it is enough if we can add convertcurreny() at the end of sum.i'm i going wrong.see the edited post